# How to write a delegated .on( "click"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, delegates

I have buttons that will be created and destroyed. I have this code below. #showContainer is what is ajax'ing, click is the action, showPrevious is the button that the user interacts with.

```
$("#showContainer").on( "click", "#showPrevious", function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "flip/showprevious.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#showContainer").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

This is valid JavaScript according to jsHint. When this is added, this and all the lines of code below it do not work. My cPanel and WAMP server is showing no errors. I have read the jQuery documentation on .on() exhaustively.

**Troubleshooting** I have tried attaching .on() to several different possible parent elements that already exist on page on load. I have tried attached .on() to other buttons to see if it was a problem with the button, but that has also not worked. I thought it might have something to do with the fact I'm recreating something that use to exist and it's confusing my code. I tried changing id to class and # to . accoridingly, but that also did not work. Regardless, none of those should have broken the javascript code anyways. I am sure it is the code I am sharing here. When I comment it out, everything else works as expected.

**A note.** I was using .click(), and it works for the first click, but after that click, the showPrevious button is recreated, and .click() will no longer work because the new showPrevious was not on the page at load.

**Summary** Well, that's all the info I have. I can't imagine the rest of the code is relevent, but if it is, tell me what to look for.

Comment: The code looks fine, and it should work. There's not much we can help you with! What version of jQuery are you using, did you check the console for errors etc ?

Comment: Can you show you HTML?

Comment: one possibility is once the content is modified there is no element with id `showPrevious`... also try `$(document).on( "click", "#showPrevious", function(){})`

Comment: once the ajax is completed... in your console try `$("#showPrevious").length`

Comment: This feels awful to admit, but adeneo has it right. I got a very old version of jquery. I'm shocked I hadn't noticed until now. I must of got it from a tutorial when I started, and have been reusing it since without issue until now. Thank you so much. This has been a struggle for many many hours.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
$(document).on("click","#showContainer #showPrevious", function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "flip/showprevious.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#showContainer").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```